# To remove some content from a file using DOS batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a file 'Text.dat' which contains some unwanted data. I need to write a DOS batch file to remove the unwanted data and put it in some other file say,'file2.dat' and leave the original file with reqired data alone. Pls help

Comment: Could you describe the unwanted data? Is it on a line by line basis? That is, if the line contains this unwanted data do you want to remove the whole line or just the data? It is also not clear if the original file should be modified at all.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for the update.. As you correctly pointed out its on line by line basis.. That is , i need to remove the entire line if it has the unwanted text. And I have to place the removed lines in another file leaving the original file with the wanted lines deleted(original file should be modified and should have only wanted data only)

Comment: Title does not match question. Please reword for SEO purposes -- I landed looking for a batch script that would REMOVE text from a file, not EXTRACT text. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `find` I would use `findstr` which is a more powerful `find`.

To create a file consisting of only the unwanted data:

`findstr "unwanted" text.dat > unwanted.dat`

To create a new file from text.dat with the "unwanted" data removed:

`findstr /v "unwanted" text.dat > text_cleaned.dat`

Online `findstr` reference can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/findstr.mspx?mfr=true).

Full command line reference:

```
C:\>findstr /?
Searches for strings in files.

FINDSTR [/B] [/E] [/L] [/R] [/S] [/I] [/X] [/V] [/N] [/M] [/O] [/P] [/F:file]
        [/C:string] [/G:file] [/D:dir list] [/A:color attributes] [/OFF[LINE]]
        strings [[drive:][path]filename[ ...]]

  /B         Matches pattern if at the beginning of a line.
  /E         Matches pattern if at the end of a line.
  /L         Uses search strings literally.
  /R         Uses search strings as regular expressions.
  /S         Searches for matching files in the current directory and all
             subdirectories.
  /I         Specifies that the search is not to be case-sensitive.
  /X         Prints lines that match exactly.
  /V         Prints only lines that do not contain a match.
  /N         Prints the line number before each line that matches.
  /M         Prints only the filename if a file contains a match.
  /O         Prints character offset before each matching line.
  /P         Skip files with non-printable characters.
  /OFF[LINE] Do not skip files with offline attribute set.
  /A:attr    Specifies color attribute with two hex digits. See "color /?"
  /F:file    Reads file list from the specified file(/ stands for console).
  /C:string  Uses specified string as a literal search string.
  /G:file    Gets search strings from the specified file(/ stands for console).
  /D:dir     Search a semicolon delimited list of directories
  strings    Text to be searched for.
  [drive:][path]filename
             Specifies a file or files to search.

Use spaces to separate multiple search strings unless the argument is prefixed
with /C.  For example, 'FINDSTR "hello there" x.y' searches for "hello" or
"there" in file x.y.  'FINDSTR /C:"hello there" x.y' searches for
"hello there" in file x.y.

Regular expression quick reference:
  .        Wildcard: any character
  *        Repeat: zero or more occurances of previous character or class
  ^        Line position: beginning of line
  $        Line position: end of line
  [class]  Character class: any one character in set
  [^class] Inverse class: any one character not in set
  [x-y]    Range: any characters within the specified range
  \x       Escape: literal use of metacharacter x
  \<xyz    Word position: beginning of word
  xyz\>    Word position: end of word
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`FIND`](http://www.computerhope.com/findhlp.htm) command.

```
find /v "unwanted" text.dat >file2.dat
```

Comment: I believe the /v switch is going to display all lines NOT containing "unwanted". From his question this is a little ambiguous, but I think he wants to put the unwanted data into another file.

Comment: @mark how would I change this so it only removes lines that exactly match a string?