# findstr /v removing space and dote not working

Tags: batch-file

I have the below batch-file:

```
cd /d "T:\R\YOU"

for /r T:\R\YOU %%i in (.) do echo %%~nxi>>D:\MultiThreading\ReadFile.txt

cd /d D:\MultiThreading
rem I want to remove dots and spaces for the file content
findstr /v "." ReadFile.pbd >> 11.txt
findstr /v " " 11.pbd >> 12.txt

pause
```

I am getting the correct output from read file, however the output of `12.txt` is empty, what I am doing wrong?

This is the output of `ReadFile.txt` file:

```
YOU
YOU 14.1.33333
YOU 14.1.44444
YOU 14.1.55555
YOU 14.1.44444
```

I want such output (I want to remove the first line):

```
YOU14133333
YOU14144444
YOU14155555
YOU14144444
```

Comment: `findstr` is only capable of searching strings but not of modifying them; use [substring replacement](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) instead...

Comment: @aschipfl I used findstr because of this question in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665505/to-remove-some-content-from-a-file-using-dos-batch-file)

Comment: `find`/`findstr` returns all *lines* of text containing at least one match unedited; the `/V` switch reverses the output, so lines containing no match are returned unedited; this allows to filter certain lines of a text file. You want to remove certain *characters*, so the commands cannot be used...

Comment: I am confused.  In your previous question you said you wanted Files listed.  The FOR /R command you are using now is enumerating folders, not files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet read the file `ReadFile.txt` skipping the first line, removes spaces and dots from every line, and outputs the result into a file called `ReturnFile.txt`:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
> "ReturnFile.txt" (
    for /F "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%L in ("ReadFile.txt") do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "LINE=!LINE: =!"
        set "LINE=!LINE:.=!"
        echo(!LINE!
        endlocal
    )
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo off
For /f "usebackq Tokens=1-10 delims=. " %%A in ("ReadFile.txt"
  ) Do If "%%B" Neq "" Echo:%%A%%B%%C%%D%%E%%F%%G%%H%%%I%%J
```

A bit primitive and rather short for answer.